# In Java, what exactly does naming an object of one type by a variable of a different type do?

Tags: java

For example, suppose this occurred:

```
DiscountSale discount = new DiscountSale();
```

Then I do this:

```
Sale discount2 = discount;
```

`Sale` is a superclass and `DiscountSale` is the subclass.

What exactly does that do in terms of which method definitions will be accessed from the Sale or DiscountSale class?

I know it references the same object in memory, but what else?

Comment: not much.  The reason for using an interface is so the implementation can be changed in one place.

Comment: I'm not sure what justifies the wave of downvotes...

Comment: yah, me neither? I was simply asking a question and researching specific to my answer did not help. I guess "experts" only want to answer complex questions

Comment: Peter - I'm sorry you received all of these downvotes.  Please don't take it personally - I'm pretty sure it's because people thought the question was a tad too broad - more of a learning question, than a specific question.  It's actually an excellent question to ask.

Comment: But I dont understand. Isn't that what this website is established for?...For people to learn?

Comment: @PeterTran One major difference is if your `DiscountSale` class introduces a `getDiscount` method for example - you will be able to write `discount.getDiscount()` but you won't be allowed to write `discount2.getDiscount()` because there is no such method in the parent `Sale` class.

Comment: @PeterTran It is ok to ask beginner level questions on stackoverflow. People possibly found your original question badly formatted and a little vague "*What does that do?*". They should have given you a chance to improve it before downvoting.

Comment: @PeterTran Actually, not directly - really, the site is for having specific questions answered, rather than general questions.  It's a grey area, though.  It does disturb me that people are so readily eager to downvote, because, as I say, it's an excellent question - just rather broad because you could easily write a book on this question as initially written - your modified question is quite a bit more specific.

Comment: I understand now....So then is there any purpose for setting that assignment up?....Meaning, is there an example of when that would be useful to reference the same object using 2 variables of different types?

Comment: @PeterTran There are thousands of examples.  This is basically a big part of the essence of object-oriented programming.  Whenever client code does not know the *specific* type of the object returned - but only its superclass - you will have an assignment such as the above, in one form or another.

Answer (score -1):

you have now 2 reference of same object. Making either reference null wont allow gc to still clear object from heap. you need to make both (all, in general) reference null.

Comment: setting references to `null` should be avoided in general.

Comment: OP already knows that it references the same object in memory. Read the question properly, before posting an answer.

Comment: @PeterLawrey any specific reason

Comment: Allowing a variable to go out of scope is usually a better idea.  Setting to `null` doesn't free up the memory immediately and can be a source of obscure bugs.

Comment: but even if variable goes out of scope, it will be in memory, so for a long run of a program, it might help system to acquire that memory. ain't it good?